# Xamarin DataPicker how to handle done button click event

Tags: xamarin, datapicker

I added to my **DataPicker** unfocused event. And in this event I would like to check if **Done** button was clicked.

```
private void DatePicker_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Or other option. 
Is it possible to add listener to button **Done**, and if was clicked then fired some method?

How can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Every UI control which receives input always has some event handlers which you can listen to.

In your case the DatePicker has an Event Handler which fires when the Date property changes.

Here is the documentation:
[DatePicker Event Handler - Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker.DateSelected/)

The implementation of this handler is simple:

```
DatePicker datePicker;
DateTime newDate;
DateTime oldDate;

public YourPage()
{
    datePicker.DateSelected += Date_DateSelected;
}

void Date_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    newDate = e.NewDate;
    oldDate = e.OldDate;
}
```

Always read the documentation first, as that's the best way to learn how to use a specific control.

Comment: What if date is not changed? And I would like to fired this method? Hmm? This is why I asked about event for "Done" button. There is nothing in documentation about it.

Comment: If date is not changed this handler won't be fired, but you'll have the oldDate as the current selected date, or the initial date that you set when the view was initialized. What's your purpose of handling the "Done" ImeOption/ImeAction event? If it's necessary for you to handle it then you need to write a custom renderer for your DatePicker to set your ICommand implementation of the ImeOption/ImeAction button.

Comment: @MalokuS FYI, I'm developing a user signup page where datapicker added for Date of Birth. Initially all fields are empty so date of birth should be empty. How do you implement this? If you simulate the implementation you will understand why done and cancel buttons event are required.